# Selenium Python - Click on radiobutton " disable = true"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm having problems when trying to click a radio button with Selenium.
I noticed in the code that the field has the option `disabled=true` as below.

This is the site's source code.

```
<div class="radio-options">
  <div class="radiobutton inline"><label><input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-number="O campo Onde está localizado o estabelecimento/domicílio? deve ser um número." disabled="true" id="Tomador_LocalDomicilio" name="Tomador.LocalDomicilio" type="radio" value="0" />Tomador não informado<span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon"></i></span></label></div>
  <div class="radiobutton inline"><label><input disabled="true" id="Tomador_LocalDomicilio" name="Tomador.LocalDomicilio" type="radio" value="1" />Brasil<span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon"></i></span></label></div>
```

Selenium gives me an error saying that the field is not clickable.
I tried some ways, how to use `execute_script`?

```
# CLICANDO NO BOTÃO DE TOMADOR
radiobutton = navegador.find_element(
    By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Tomador_LocalDomicilio"]')

navegador.execute_script(
    "arguments[0].click()", radiobutton)
```

Comment: The `disabled=true` on the INPUT means that it's disabled... you can't click on it. That's why Selenium is telling you it's not clickable. I'm not sure what your goal here is.

Comment: My goal is to click on the disabled input. I'm issuing an Invoice, and the borrower is from Brazil, however his check is "NOT INFORMED" by default.

Comment: The UI is disabled because that INPUT is not intended to be enabled at that point. You need to find out (using the UI) what you need to do to enable the INPUT as a user would. You do not want to use JS to get around this. Doing so could cause problems with the site or with your submission because it's going to be unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

If goal is to check disabled element (otherwise I don't see any point to click on it), you can use native js element property `checked`

```
navegador.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('#Tomador_LocalDomicilio')[1].checked = true")
```

where index 1 is index of Brasil and 0 is index of Tomador não informado

Comment: Thanks friend, he actually selected the field "BRASIL". In reality I need a click, because when clicking it will open a field to enter the company's data.

Comment: @BrunoLopes can you use `ActionChains`?
`actionChains = ActionChains(driver)`
`actionChains.move_to_element(radiobutton).click().perform()`

Comment: It didn't work, it doesn't even work with Pyautogui, mouseDown, MouseUp. It went bad over here. Hahaha

Comment: @BrunoLopes can you provide your resource or DOM part that does logic you desctibed? It's difficult to help you without reproducible example